# How to solve this nonlinear differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, nonlinear, boundary-condition-at-infinity

The given nonlinear differential equation is

```
y'''[t]+(y[t]*y''[t])+y[t]'^2-1=0
```

with boundary conditions `{y[0]=0,y'[0]=0` and `y'[t]->1` as `t->Infinity`.

Comment: Have a look into the documentation of `DSolve` and `NDSolve`.

Comment: Your question needs more from your side. Here its considered helpful and polite to show your own efforts and share your data and code attempts in a well [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help), so we can quickly see the problem you are facing. Please help us to help you and [edit your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) accordingly. Also, please take the [tour], it will help you understand the site. If  you write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) it will inspire great answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Answer substantially revised.*

**Numerical Solution**

This question looks similar to [100659](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/100671/1063), so one might expect to solve it in the same way.  For instance, write

```
tmax = 1000; 
s = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y'''[t] + y[t]*y''[t] + y'[t]^2 - 1 == 0, 
    y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, y''[0] == c}, y, {t, 0, tmax}, {c}];
```

and then apply `FindRoot` to `s[c][tmax] == 1` to find the value of `c` for which `y'[tmax] == 1`.  `NDSolve` with the option `Method -> {Shooting, ...}` would be expected to have the same result.  However, for this question a range of `c` satisfy the outer boundary condition.  This can be seen by plotting solutions for several values of `c`.

```
Plot[{s[-1.08637576][t], s[-1][t], s[0][t], s[1][t], s[3][t], s[10][t]}, 
    {t, 0, tmax/50}, AxesLabel -> {t, y}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Medium]] 
Plot[{s[-1.08637576]'[t], s[-1]'[t], s[0]'[t], s[1]'[t], s[3]'[t], s[10]'[t]}, 
    {t, 0, tmax/50}, AxesLabel -> {t, y'}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Medium], 
    PlotRange -> {-1, 5}]
{s[-1.08637576]'[tmax], s[-1]'[tmax], s[0]'[tmax], s[1]'[tmax], s[3]'[tmax], s[10]'[tmax]}
```

[image]

[image]

```
(* {1., 1., 1., 1., 1.00001, 1.00005} *)
```

For values of `c` smaller than about `-1.08637576`, the solution is singular at finite `t`.

**Symbolic Solution**

Interestingly, this question also can be solved symbolically.  First, observe that the ODE can be written as

```
D[y'[t] + y[t]^2/2, {t, 2}] -1 == 0
```

Obviously, this can be twice integrated.  Set `z[t] == y'[t] + y[t]^2/2`, and

```
(Flatten@DSolve[{z''[t] == 1, z[0] == 0}, z[t], t] // Apart) /. C[2] -> c
(* {z[t] -> c t + t^2/2} *)
```

So, the ODE can be rewritten as a first-order differential equation,

```
y'[t] + y[t]^2/2 == t^2/2 + c t
```

with the remaining boundary condition, `y[0] == 0`.  Then, `DSolve` yields

```
Simplify@DSolveValue[{y'[t] + y[t]^2/2 == t^2/2 + c t, y[0] == 0}, y[t], t]
```

> > (-(c + t) ParabolicCylinderD[1/4 (-2 - c^2), I (c + t)] (c ParabolicCylinderD[1/4 (-2 + c^2), c] - 
> >           2 ParabolicCylinderD[1/4 (2 + c^2), c]) - 
> >        2 I ParabolicCylinderD[1/4 (2 - c^2), 
> >          I (c + t)] (c ParabolicCylinderD[1/4 (-2 + c^2), c] - 
> >           2 ParabolicCylinderD[1/4 (2 + c^2), c]) + (c ParabolicCylinderD[
> >             1/4 (-2 - c^2), I c] + 
> >           2 I ParabolicCylinderD[1/2 - c^2/4, 
> >             I c]) ((c + t) ParabolicCylinderD[1/4 (-2 + c^2), c + t] - 
> >           2 ParabolicCylinderD[1/4 (2 + c^2), 
> >             c + t]))/((c ParabolicCylinderD[1/4 (-2 - c^2), I c] + 
> >           2 I ParabolicCylinderD[1/2 - c^2/4, I c]) ParabolicCylinderD[
> >          1/4 (-2 + c^2), c + t] + 
> >        ParabolicCylinderD[1/4 (-2 - c^2), 
> >          I (c + t)] (c ParabolicCylinderD[1/4 (-2 + c^2), c] - 
> >           2 ParabolicCylinderD[1/4 (2 + c^2), c]))

Plotting this expression yields the same curves as above with the denominator becoming singular for `c` about equal to `-1.08637574066271760496838769091`.

Comment: Please let me know the theory related to this differential equation. Is it related to Boundary Layer problems ?

Comment: @ChetanWaghela  I do not understand what you are asking in the your comment.  Please clarify.

Comment: @bbgodfrey could you please give an example of how to apply FindRoot to get the value of c for which the BC is satisfied? I have tried to make it but it's not working.

Comment: @Perhaps, I was not sufficiently clear.  I began by saying that "This question looks similar to 100659, so one might expect to solve it in the same way.", which is to say, run the two lines of code at the beginning of my answer, followed by something like `FindRoot[s[c]'[tmax] == 1, {c, 0}]`, but it does not converge well for this question, because all values of `c > -1.08637574066271760496838769091` satisfy the outer boundary condition.  I demonstrated this by solving the ODE for many values of `c`, as shown in the plots.