# Solving an ordinary differential equation with boundary condition at infinity

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I want to solve the following differential equation

```
f''[z] + (1/z)*f'[z] - f[z] + f[z]^3 == 0
```

subject to the boundary conditions

$$f^{\prime}(0)=0\qquad\lim_{z\to\infty}f(z)=0$$
The solution for R subject to these boundary conditions is known as Townes soliton. I have followed what is shown in the example solved here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/156362/73726.

What I have tried so far is the following:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{f''[z] + (1/z)*f'[z] - f[z] + f[z]^3 == 0, f[5] == 0, f'[0] == 0}, f, {z, 0, 5}, Method -> { "Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" ->{f[5] == 100, f'[0] == 0}}];Plot[sol[z], {z, 0, 5}, AxesLabel -> {z, f}]
```

But it is retuning the following errors

> NDSolve`Shooting::ndcinit: Initial conditions should be specified at a single point.

> NDSolveValue::dsvar: 0.00010214285714285715` cannot be used as a variable.
>
> General::stop: Further output of NDSolveValue::dsvar will be suppressed during this calculation.

Comment: Please include your expression in MMA form and the code you have tried so far.

Comment: @MarcoB I have just updated it. Hope it is adequated now.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps:

```
 $Version
 (*"12.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)"*)

 sol = With[{e = 10^-30}, 
 NDSolveValue[{f''[z] + (1/z)*f'[z] - f[z] + f[z]^3 == 0, 
 f[200] == 0, f'[e] == 0}, f, {z, e, 200}, 
 Method -> {"Shooting", 
 "StartingInitialConditions" -> {f[e] == -21, f'[e] == 0}}, 
 MaxSteps -> 10^6, WorkingPrecision -> 25]]; Plot[
 sol[z], {z, 0, 200}, AxesLabel -> {z, f}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: The command of Maple 2021 `evalf(dsolve({diff(f(z), z, z) + diff(f(z), z)/z - f(z) + f(z)^3 = 0, f(0) = 1/3, D(f)(0) = 0}, f(z), series, order = 20))` produces $f(z)= 0.3333333333+ 0.07407407407 z^{2}+ 0.003086419753 z^{4}- 0.00009525986892 z^{6}- 0.00001448743840 z^{8}- 5.587696941\times10^{-7} z^{10}+ 1.259010856\times10^{-8} z^{12}+ 2.608548074\times10^{-9} z^{14}+ 1.185138978\times10^{-10} z^{16}- 1.313655828\times10^{-12} z^{18}+\mathrm{O}(z^{20}) $. Since the coefficients rapidly decrease, it looks similar to a trunskated power expansion of a certain entire function.