# Numerically solving an ODE depending on an unknown boundary value

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear

I am trying to solve a ODE related to its boundary value with `NDSolve`

```
NDSolve[
  {f'''[x] + 1/2*f[x]*f''[x] + f''[0] == 0, 
   f'[0] == 0, f[0] == 0, f'[1000] == 1}, 
  f, {x, 0, 10}]
```

The error message is:

> NDSolve::litarg: To avoid possible ambiguity, the arguments of the dependent variable in {(f^′′)[0]+1/2 f[η] (f^′′)[η]+(f^(3))[η]==0} should literally match the independent variables.

I guess the issue is that I cannot define the boundary value within the equation in this way. How could I add this term into equation and solve it?

Comment: Your ode do not make too much sense. What is `f''[0]` doing in the ODE itself? This is a constant. So you could just as well write `NDSolve[{f'''[x]+1/2*f[x]*f''[x]+c==0.....` or may be you meant to have it in the B.C. but then you have too many boundary conditions

Comment: `f''[0]` is unknown. The ODE is still with three boundary conditions

Comment: You have 3rd order ODE, and you have given 3 boundary conditions already.

Comment: Yes. BCs are enough to solve the ODE. However, f''[0] is also involved into the equation.

Comment: Your ODE is equivalent to $f'''(x)+f(x)f''(x)/2+c=0$ with the boundary conditions $f'(0)=f(0)=0$, $f'(1000)=1$ and $f''(0)=0$. So it is equivalent to a third ODE with _four_ BCs. I don't think there is a solution for an arbitrary $c$. Even if there were, you cannot solve numerically a problem with an unspecified BC (and thus not your equivalent problem either).

Comment: If you want to be convinced, solve e.g. `NDSolve[{f'''[x] + 1/2*f[x]*f''[x] + c == 0, f'[0] == 0, f[0] == 0,  f'[3] == 1}, f, {x, 0, 3}]` for different values of `c`: you see that you have no additional degree of freedom for `f''[0]`.

Comment: It appears that `f[x]` must approach `x` asymptotically as `x` approaches infinity to satisfy the outer boundary condition.  If so, then `f'''[x]` and `f''[x]` must approach `0` faster than `1/x`, and `f''[0]` them must be identically `0`.  So, there appears to be no solution satisfying the boundary conditions.  Incidentally, the ODE here bears some similarity to [100659](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/100671/1063), which can be solved.  See also [104170](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118911/1063).

Comment: Thank you all for the help. In fact, my issue is about how to code a term in the ODE that depends on a boundary value `F(f''(0))`, I am pretty sure there is a solution for the original equation.

Answer (score 1):

You get a solution when searching for f''[0]==c

```
g[y_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] := f[y] /. First@
     NDSolve[{f'''[x] + 1/2*f[x]*f''[x] + c == 0, f'[0] == 0, f[0] == 0,
              f''[0] == c}, f, {x, 0, 1000}]

h[y_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] := f'[y] /. First@
     NDSolve[{f'''[x] + 1/2*f[x]*f''[x] + c == 0, f'[0] == 0, f[0] == 0,
              f''[0] == c}, f, {x, 0, 1000}]

cfr = c /. First@FindRoot[h[1000, c] == 1, {c, -.03}, WorkingPrecision -> 20, 
                     AccuracyGoal -> 8, PrecisionGoal -> 8]

(*    -0.025783801817875997941    *)

h[1000, cfr]

(*    1.    *)

Plot[g[y, cfr], {y, 0, 10}, GridLines -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image]